# Let $A=\mathbb C[x] $ prove there is no norm on $A$ in which it is a C* algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A=\mathbb C[x] $ prove there is no norm on A in which it makes a C* algebra.

i think this is true because the spec(a) is infinity for any $a\in A$ ? but im not sure how to prove it.

I did try verifying the axioms for a norm but im not sure what a* in this case

Comment: First sentence doesn't make sense.  Looks unfinished

Comment: The idea is no norm exists that makes A into a C* algebra

Comment: I don't know of *any* norm on $\Bbb C[x]$ maybe that's why I upvoted your question; but can you give some definitions/links to how norms on $C[x]$ are supposed to work?

Comment: Supposed to prove that there does not exist a norm on the set A so that it is a C* algebra. So no I can't cause there isn't one...

Comment: It should break one of the rules of being a norm but im not sure which

Comment: Suppose we just wanted a plain old ***algebra norm*** on $\Bbb C[x]$; or even just a really plain old ***Banach space*** norm.  How would that look?  I've never see such a thing . . .

Comment: By the way, where did you get this question?

Comment: OK, here's an issue:  what happens when we try to make $\Bbb C[x]$ complete in some norm?  Will it still contain only polynomials?

Comment: @RobertLewis. An infinite-dimensional Banach space cannot have a countable Hamel (vector-space) basis.

Comment: @RobertLewis you can consider B the field of quotients of A but this is also not a C* algebra because spec(a) is empty so r(a) is undefined, so no you cannot canonically complete it.

Comment: @Faust:  how do you define $\text{spec}(A)$ and $r(A)$?

Comment: Should be clear in the answer now how they are defined for $a\in A$ you cant define them for the whole space i dont think. @RobertLewis

Comment: @RobertLewis: There are tons of algebra norms on $\mathbb{C}[x]$.  Just fix some infinite bounded subset $X\subset\mathbb{C}$ and take the sup norm for polynomials as functions on $X$, for instance.  Of course, these norms are not complete.

Comment: @EricWofsey where were you for the last 3 hours that ive been trying to figure this out ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that for any $a\in A $ the $spec(a)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}| \lambda 1 - a \space\text{is not invertable}\} $ and $r(a)=\sup\{|\lambda| s.t \lambda \in spec(a) \}$

Theorem: if a $*$-algebra posses a norm in which it is a C*algebra, then it possesses only one such norm.

Theorem: If a is a self adjiont element of a unital C*algebra A then $||a||=r(a)$ but $r(a) = \infty $ for everything which is clearly not finite.

Hence there is no norm on A that makes it into a C* algebra.